# Pandas read_json value_error, Type_erroe

Tags: json, pandas, typeerror, valueerror

```
url = 'https://api.misoenergy.org/MISORTWDDataBroker/DataBrokerServices.asmx?messageType=getace&returnType=json'

pd.read_json(url)
```

ValueError: Expected object or value

```
pd.read_json(url, lines= True)
```

TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

json sample:

```
{"MktDay":"11-19-2020","RefId":"19-Nov-2020 - Interval 14:10:00 EST","ACE":[{"instantEST":"2020-11-19 12:10:30 PM","value":"-60.95"},{"instantEST":"2020-11-19 12:11:00 PM","value":"172.85"},{"instantEST":"2020-11-19 12:11:30 PM","value":"344.70"}
```

Comment: The first code block works for me (python 3.9.5, pandas 1.2.0). Something else is wrong.

Comment: Check your pandas version.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your examples worked for me.

you can try this as an option:

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://api.misoenergy.org/MISORTWDDataBroker/DataBrokerServices.asmx?messageType=getace&returnType=json')
pd.read_json(data.text)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. not sure why for the same URL, pd.read_json wont work, but requests.get would